# canvas.move not moving in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a circle that I want to move around a map, I am in the early stages,  but I've looked in many places and can't figure out why the circle isn't moving. my code is

```
import Tkinter as Tkinter

class gameScreen:
    def moveup(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.char, -100, 0)
        self.canvas.focus(self.char)
        self.canvas.update()

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        master.title("Game")

        master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "platformer.gif")
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width=self.img.width(),
                                             height=self.img.height())

        self.canvas.pack(expand="YES",fill="both")

        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0,anchor="nw", image = self.img)
        self.char = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "hero.gif")
        self.canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50, fill="red")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        master.bind("<Up>", self.moveup)        

root = tkinter.Tk()
my_gui = gameScreen(root)
root.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the `move` method an id or tag for an object on the canvas. The id is returned when you create the canvas item.

```
class gameScreen:
    def moveup(self, event):
        ...
        self.canvas.move(self.canvas_item, -100, 0)
        ...

    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.canvas_item = self.canvas.create_oval(...)
        ...
```